# Разработка бекдора в Kernel Android OC

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-service, kernel, android-testing

Господа. Моя задача: написать apk, которая сможет достучатся до kernel и:

1. захватить обработку драйверов (или обернуть как-то, не знаю)
2. создать системную службу
3. создать драйвер
4. создать некий драйвер/службу а-ля rdp для того, чтобы удалённо накатывать патчи + IO вывод информации на удалённый темринал

Прошу, подскажите мануал конкретно по этой области. Со структурой Android OC **немного** знаком, времени на изучение мало.
Сам разработчик .NET C#.

Интерес к этому делу убивает, но не могу позволить себе по времени целые тома читать
Прошу помощи, грасиа

Comment: Я много чего повидал. Странная у вас ориентация. Я еще понимаю за девочками подглядывать в селфи-камеру смартфона, или денег украсть, или зашифровать диск и попросить выкуп за ключ для расшифровки... Но чтобы стучать по ядру, захватывать обработку драйверов, создавать системные службы и драйверы чтобы удалённо накладывать патчи...

Comment: @DiD Приму как комплимент D:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скину несколько ссылок на разные исходные коды. Судя по вашей осведомлённости, они вам не сильно помогут (т.к. вам ещё "целые тома читать" и читать). Ломать - не строить. А так, надеюсь, сообществу будет полезно в копилочку.

- [Advance Android Malware Analysis Framework](https://github.com/droidefense/engine)
- [Android Malware Example](https://github.com/geeksonsecurity/android-overlay-malware-example)
- [Generic Android Deobfuscator](https://github.com/CalebFenton/simplify)
- [MAD-Spy](https://github.com/CristianTuretta/MAD-Spy)
- [anti-emulator](https://github.com/strazzere/anti-emulator)
- [Java Ransomware](https://github.com/PanagiotisDrakatos/JavaRansomware)
- [Android-Elite-Virus](https://github.com/harshalbenake/Android-Elite-Virus)
- [fakegumtree](https://github.com/harryfrey/fakegumtree)
- [SimpleSpyware](https://github.com/7homasSutter/SimpleSpyware)
- [AndroidSpyCamera](https://github.com/TwoEightNine/AndroidSpyCamera)
- [Dobermann](https://github.com/bioverflow/Dobermann)
- [SpyGen](https://github.com/HouariZegai/SpyGen)
- [ADO Bot](https://github.com/TheRipperJhon/AdoBot)
- [Simple Android Spyware](https://github.com/tyalymov/Simple-android-spyware)

Comment: О, Господи! Сорсы - то что нужно!! Поклон до колен Вам!